# pyelasticsearch mapping overwritten

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a mapping of :

```
{
    properties: {
        field1: {
            index: not_analyzed
            omit_norms: true
            index_options: docs
            type: string
        }
       },
       _parent: {

       type: parent_doctype
       }
   }
}
```

All I do is index items (using the "elasticsearch-HEAD" plugin, or a python client pyelasticsearch)
FOr some reason, sometime my mapping seems to get corrupted - the "_parent" part of the mapping vanishes, and all the parents of existing documents vanish also.

This is terrible, since I cannot rely on my DB, and item might be corrupted.

I did NOT use any further mapping API calls. What could cause this?

I had some idea that it happens when trying to index with PUT instead of POST or something like that?

Can _index change the mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I actually erased my own mapping.
trying to delete a document i sent:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_doctype'
```

Then when I indexed another document, the maping was autogenerated, but withouth the _parent mapping.

awkward....

Comment: I did this exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the answer!